# How to place close button of drawer layout such a way that ejecting half portion towards outside as seen in picture

Tags: android

How to place close button of drawer layout such a way that ejecting half portion towards outside as seen in picture:

[image]

Comment: Add close button on left hand side of your drawer and try to set negative margin for it. And show only when drawer open, hide it on drawer close.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a overlay layout like Relativelayout

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"(40 is height of view at top plus 8dp is half height of this own view)
        android:marginLeft="8dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:marginLeft="16dp">

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make two different horizontal layout and add the arrow button in first horizontal layout according to the position. The remaining things add in second horizontal layout.